# Multiform data form with PHP CURL

Tags: php, ajax, forms, curl

How do you serialize the following code and make the static variable above listen to a previous form input?

How do I post multi form data with the following, please help.

```
    <?php

        $dest = 'phonenumber'; 
        $user = 'username'; 
        $pass = 'passowrd';

            $ch = curl_init("http://hlr.routotelecom.com/"); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "number=$dest&user=$user&pass=$pass"); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('field1=value&field2=value2'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
            $output = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch);
            echo print_r(json_decode($output), 1);


?>
```

Comment: What does it do, what do you want it to do, how do you serialize code and where does a static variable come into play? Or: please provide a clear description of what you want to do (which "post multi form data" isn't) and why you cannot succeed in that.

Comment: It has to query an HLR website and return JSON results, that part is working, the problem is customizing the 'phoneumber' part to be from a user input form

Comment: "Customizing the phonenumber part" is still not clear enough for us to answer your question. Update your question with what you do, what happens, and what you expect.

Comment: I managed to request data from the form by modifying 'code' $dest = $_REQUEST['number'];

Answer (score 1):

Don't build your own query string. Curl will happily accept an array and do it for you:

```
$data = array(
    'number' => $dest,
    'user' => $user,
    'pass' => $pass
);

curl_setopt($ch, CUROPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Comment: I succeeded with $dest = $_REQUEST['number'];